# cascade filters where data are from api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to implement a cascading filter. Everytime a user select from Transaction Type Drowndown it will call `getTransactionSubType` and depending on the selected item on the Transaction Type Drowndown that will be the `this.payloadFilter.transactionType` which will use as parameter to retrieved data from `getTransactionSubType` and display the data on Transaction Sub Type.

Now I am not pretty confident with the implementation below  cause I am also noticing a bit of delay on the data of transaction sub type every time I change or select an item from transaction type, it this a good solution or is this a better way to do this ?

Help would be much appreciated , Thanks.

[image]

[image]

#html code

```
<div class="report-filter-container">
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
          <mat-label>Transaction Type</mat-label>
          <mat-select 
            multiple
            #selectElemTransactionTypes
            [(value)]="reportFilter.transactionType"
            (selectionChange)="changeFilter('transactionType',selectAllTransactionTypes)"> `
            <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
              <mat-checkbox
                #selectAllTransactionTypes
                color="primary"
                (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('transactionType',selectElemTransactionTypes, selectAllTransactionTypes)">
                  Select All
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.transactionType" [value]="f.name">
              {{f.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
          <mat-label>Transaction Sub Type</mat-label>
          <mat-select 
            multiple
            #selectElemTransactionSubTypes
            [(value)]="reportFilter.transactionSubType"
            (selectionChange)="changeFilter('transactionSubType',selectAllTransactionSubTypes)"> `
            <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
              <mat-checkbox
                #selectAllTransactionSubTypes
                color="primary"
                (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('transactionSubType',selectElemTransactionSubTypes, selectAllTransactionSubTypes)">
                  Select All
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.transactionSubType" [value]="f">
              {{f}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

Hi, I am trying to implement a cascading filter which data are from the API.So everytime user select from the

#Ts code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getTransactionType();
  this.getTransactionSubType();
}

toggleAllSelectionFilter(selectProp: string, selectElem:MatSelect, selectAll: MatCheckbox) {    
  let isSelectAllSelected = this.isAllSelected[selectProp];
  const checkSelAllOption = !isSelectAllSelected;
  selectElem.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => (checkSelAllOption)? item.select(): item.deselect());
  this.isAllSelected[selectProp] = checkSelAllOption;   
  setTimeout(()=>{
    selectAll.checked = checkSelAllOption;
  },0)    
}

changeFilter(filterName:string, selectAll: MatCheckbox){    
  this.isAllSelected[filterName] = (this.reportFilter[filterName].length === this.filters[filterName].length);
  this.payloadFilter[filterName] = JSON.stringify(this.reportFilter[filterName]);
  selectAll.checked = this.isAllSelected[filterName];

  if(filterName === 'transactionType') {
    this.getTransactionSubType();

  }
}

getTransactionSubType(){
  let payloadFiltertransactionType = JSON.parse(this.payloadFilter.transactionType);
  this._transSubTypeService.getTransactionSubtype(this.accountName,payloadFiltertransactionType)
  .subscribe(
    res =>{                
      if (res.isSuccess) {
        this.filters.transactionSubType = res.data;
      }
    },
    err => {
      this.dialog.closeAll();
      this._notificationService.showError('Encountered an error. Please try again.');
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: would you be able to create a minimum reproducible problem here  https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy ? (if so, you could update your question with a link to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is the dynamic data that you need to fetch based on the first drop down then whatever you implemented is good.

Yes, there is a scope for improvement like:

1. Don't populate transaction subtype upfront and load only when at least one item from the first dropdown is selected.
2. Show the whole screen level loader as soon as you update the first dropdown until you fetch subtypes. or you can try the loader inside the dropdown.
3. Try implementing cache.